# Cannot redirect to index.html page after signing in

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-2.7, basehttpserver

My client app first takes user_ID and password from login.html page and then as "Sign In" button is pressed, a function "display()" runs that stored ID and password from input fields and sends it to Server. the server approves the login ID and password and tries to sent index.html page. But I am unable to sent the index.html page. May be I am missing something in my HTML code or Server side.

my HTML(bootstrap) code is;

```
          <input type="text" id="user_id" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User ID" >

          <input type="password" id="password_id" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" >

          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="Display()" > Sign In link</button>
```

JavaScript "Display()" function:

```
        <script>

    function Display(){
                var ID = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
                var passwrd = document.getElementById("password_id").value;
                var login = "/login:" + ID + "-" + passwrd + "--" ;

                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", login, true); 
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {          if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
               var data = http.responseText;
                        if (data=="0"){
            document.getElementById("info_id").innerHTML =  "wrong password";
            } 
                        else if (data=="1"){
            document.getElementById("info_id").innerHTML =  "logging in as Admin";
            page();
            }           

        }
        }
        http.send(null); 
             }
    function page(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                //document.body.className = 'ok';
                //console.log(request.responseText);
            } else {
                //document.body.className = 'error';
            }
            }
        };
        request.open("GET", "index.html" , true);
        request.send(null);

      }
    </script>
```

Python baseHTTPServer code is :

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_HEAD(s):
    s.send_response(200)
    s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    s.end_headers()


def do_GET(s):
    HTTP_request=s.requestline
    index_1=HTTP_request.index("GET /")
    index_2=HTTP_request.index(" HTTP/1.1")
    file_name=HTTP_request[index_1+5:index_2]
    print 'HTTP_request:',HTTP_request 
    if HTTP_request.find('login')>-1:
        print 'got', file_name  # file name is formatted as "login:anum-1234--"
        ID = file_name[6:file_name.find('-')]
        password = file_name[file_name.find('-')+1:file_name.find('--')]
        if ID == "anum" and password == "1234":
            admin = 1
            print 'admin ENTERED'  # <--working till here
            file1=open('index.html','r')
            file_read=file1.read()
            s.send_response(301)
            s.send_header('Location','http://index.html') # <- is it correct this way ?
            #s.send_header('Location',file_read)  ## <- or this way
            s.end_headers() 
        else:
            admin = 0  
            s.wfile.write("0")
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not use a proper framework?

Comment: M sorry, I am very new at all this. I just want to know how to redirect to a new page.

Comment: But this isn't something you should do like this, especially if you're new. Install [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and follow the introduction there.